# how to restrict the user without login

Tags: asp.net

i created some pages in asp.net. but i want to allow the users only if he is login. how to do that. is there any controls available for that one. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `web.config` there is a section below `<system.web>` where you can add:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

It is normal that you put pages that requires login in a certain sub-directory and thus you can put a new `web.config` in that folder with the above lines inside `<system.web>`, this will prevent unauthorized access.

[MSDN has a great section about Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh.aspx) that I recommend you to read.

Comment: @Flip thank you. but after login the page if we click back button then the would be signed out automatically.. how it would be?

Comment: @Mihir, you will need to call `SignOut` in order to sign out someone from code behind. However, I don't think that there will be a postback when you click the back-button, it will load the html from Cache.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a login page that uses Forms Authentication.

See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_aspnetforms)